# Height of notification incorrect "match_parent"

Tags: android, notifications, height

I try to make a custom view with this xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i run notification with this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout); 

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContent(remoteViews).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

    mNotificationManager.notify(20, mBuilder.build());
}
```

This is the result:

[image: screenshot]

why "match_parent" does not use the full height of the notification ?

I want the red zone does the same height as the notification, without use "dip" unity.  I use android 4.2.2. Thank you !

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. I will try to repro this when I get off work. Try changing the image view's layout_width to match_parent just for fun. It shouldn't happen but my only thought is the image is being scaled to the width based on the original ratio and the view is fitting to that.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using a RelativeLayout instead? And also play around with these attributes in the ImageView tag

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! Please don't use answers for something that's not an answer. If you've earned enough reputation then you can comment at every question and answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how the above is not an answer. As mentioned in the latter part of my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099589/incorrect-height-of-remoteviews-notification-when-using-linear-layout, this worked for me. This, however, is only a workaround and as mentioned in my question, may not be applicable in all cases :) Hence my asking for trying it for this use case.

Comment: Actually, trying relative layout shouldn't be required, only the just changing those imageview attributes should work.
Hello asker, still looking an answer? :P Lemme know if my solution works for you.