# Incorrect height of RemoteViews notification when using linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications

I've created a notification using RemoteViews with a custom layout. The layout structure is as below.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="6"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="8dp"
      android:paddingTop="8.0dip" >
  </LinearLayout> 
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="4"
      android:divider="?android:listDivider"
      android:dividerPadding="12.0dip"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:showDividers="middle|beginning" >
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The effect of it all appears only in a fraction of the notification height, and not in the full height of the notification. E.g. check-out the buttons in the screenshot at http://i57.tinypic.com/14dzo9i.png (the middle notification is the focus of the question), which are in the last child of the parent LinearLayout, and should be all vertically centre-aligned.

My question is very similar to [Height of notification incorrect "match_parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052004/height-of-notification-incorrect-match-parent), but since there isn't a real answer present there, I'm asking this. The answer on that question does refer to a way to dynamically figure out the notification height. If that is the solution to use, I'd like to know how to use the height obtained from there to dynamically set the height of the remote view, since I don't see a height setter on the remote views object.

Please note that the height of the image is fine when I use a relative layout instead. Relative layout still has two problems: 1. the buttons are still not vertically centre-aligned and 2. I can only wrap content or fill parent, not divide the available space into the two children linear layouts. Screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/o1000j.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working on changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for the views within. Somehow missed it earlier, interesting though the behaviour for this combination of values.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Layout to RelativeLayout and use param android:toLeftOf="@+id/...", android:toRightOf="@+id/..." to align your subView in layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```